# Titanium Appcelerator back button closes my window

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

I'm working on building my first Android app on Titanium.
I have an RSS feed loading on the first window, then after clicking a link from the rss list, I create a new window and display the full content of the rss item on that page.

What I want to achieve is that when I'm on the second window (full content of rss feed) and press the Back button from my phone, I want to return to the first window (rss list). At the moment my app exits when pressing the back button from anywhere from my app.

On the first window, I have specified `exitOnClose: true` and on the second I have specified `exitOnClose: false`. Not sure if that's what I need to do.

Any help is much appreciated & thanks in advance.

Maikel

Comment: Check out the discussion about this problem here: http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/2731/adding-a-window-to-the-stack

Answer (score 7):

I found the answer.

When I open a new window, I just pass `modal:true` and that fixes it

Comment: Another thing that helps is creating the window with fullscreen: false

Answer (score 3):

Let try

```
var btnMap = Ti.UI.createButton ({
    title:'Click here to open map',
    width:300, height:50, top:100
});
win.add(btnMap);
btnMap.addEventListener('click', function(){
    var mapWin = Titanium.UI.createWindow({  
        title:'France Map',
        tabBarHidden:true,
        url:'francemap.js'
    }); 
    Ti.UI.currentTab.open(mapWin);
});
```

It means you should use `Ti.UI.currentTab.open(mapWin)` instead of use `mapWin.open()`. Remember that always use tab to manage your window.

Comment: Is there any way to add navigation bar in titanium?

Answer (score 0):

If you open a new window with and it has a bar at the top it will have a button to the previous page automatically. You can also put a button into the bar on your own

```
var back = Ti.UI.createButton({
    title: "Back",
    style:Titanium.UI.iPhone.SystemButtonStyle.BORDERED
});
back.addEventListener("click", function() {
    Ti.UI.currentWindow.close();
});
Ti.UI.currentWindow.setLeftNavButton(back);
```